# Preserve size while rotating image

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to rotate Arrow with Imagick in PHP code. Currently I'm using `rotateImage()`. I'm trying to get "basic" angles of cardinal directions - by 22,5°. My problem is shown in those images. Rotated arrow is a little bit smaller - here it isn't visible as much, but when I place into map, it's visible a lot, and arrows rotate f.e. to WNW (292.5°) are really small. Is there any way how to rotate image, that it will keep the size of the arrow?

[image: Rotated image]

[image: Original image]

Edit: Image after Danack's code:

```
$originalWidth = $this->image->getImageWidth();
    $originalHeight = $this->image->getImageHeight();

    $this->image->rotateimage(new ImagickPixel('#00000000'), $angle);

    $newWidth = $this->image->getImageWidth();
    $newHeight = $this->image->getImageHeight();

    $this->image->cropImage(
        $originalWidth,
        $originalHeight,
        ($newWidth - $originalWidth) / 2,
        ($newHeight - $originalHeight) / 2
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Updated code below with `setImagePage` reset.

Comment: Can I ask, what is the `$crop`? Or how it should be defined?

Comment: It was just true or false from the demo page.

Comment: Ok, I'll remove if statement. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't that the image is shrinking, it is that the image is getting bigger, but then you're displaying it at the same size, which make the arrow portion appear smaller.

You can either set the background color to be something other than white to see this, or visit the demo at: http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/rotateImage

What you need to do is crop the image back to the original size after you have rotated it.

```
$imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
$originalWidth = $imagick->getImageWidth();
$originalHeight = $imagick->getImageHeight();

$imagick->rotateImage($color, $angle);


    $imagick->setImagePage(
        $imagick->getimageWidth(),
        $imagick->getimageheight(),
        0,
        0
    );

    $imagick->cropImage(
        $originalWidth,
        $originalHeight,
        ($imagick->getimageWidth() - $originalWidth) / 2,
        ($imagick->getimageHeight() - $originalHeight) / 2
    );


header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
```

Additionally, Imagick::rotateImage appears to be one of the functions that leaves the 'image page' with information about the new geometry in it. You almost certainly want to reset the image page before calling any other function on it that is affected by geometry such as cropping.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try as soon as I get to PC with the script.

Comment: Now the arrows are "bigger", but are cutted. I'll add new image into original question.